# Can I get the any venue tips/photos from any foursquare venue through my php application?

Tags: php, foursquare

Can I get the venue tips/photos from any foursquare venue through my php application? Are all the api calls free?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API calls are free, but there is a usage policy, here are the resources you need to read in order to do what you ask for:

- [Platform Rules](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues)
- [To get Tips](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips)
- [To get Photos](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos)

Note that in stand of making two calls, you can make a single call to '[venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues)', which will get you both the tips and photos (but not all photos, I think 6 max)